# Add comments of the post of the facebook on the stream LIVE

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, stream, comments, live

I am streaming on facebook, and i would like to add the COMMENTS of the STREAM POST on the video.

Is it possible?

I searched on facebook's development site, found a lot of materials about puting the post, an UNIQUE comment, but not all the news comments that people are posting live.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why would you do that? The comments are under the video

Comment: Because if someone is watching on fullscreen for exemple, they can see the comments on the video.

Comment: Shouldn't the user choose that. Why force every user to see the comments in the video?

Comment: well man, it is just little letters on the video, do you know how to do it?

Comment: No I have no idea